# Transmission of CSRF tokens from client to server

Tags: web-application, csrf

I was reading up on the usage of CSRF tokens at `https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf/tokens` and one section mentioned it should be transmitted to the client in a hidden field in a HTML form.

How about guidelines on how the client transmits it back to the server? I suppose it should be ok to put it in either GET or POST parameters since the client is just returning the unique value and not the party generating it? Or must it be in a POST parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSRF is only relevant for state-changing requests, which per the HTTP spec *should* never happen for GET requests. Of course people violate this spec all the time, but still, if you have to ask "is it OK to send anti-CSRF tokens in the URL?" you really should be asking "does this state-changing request really need to be a GET?".

With that said, anti-CSRF tokens can be sent in the URL, or in the body, or even in headers (in fact, in some ways custom headers are the most secure option, as usually those can't be sent cross-origin at all). URL is definitely not ideal - URLs are the most likely thing to be logged or otherwise exposed, and you don't want security-sensitive values in logs or exposed - but if you have to do it, it's probably OK (though ideally you would rotate the anti-CSRF token afterwards).

---

Also, a word of warning: While they are best known for their quite good Burp Suite software, Portswigger has some... very old-fashioned, and kind of out-of-touch, ideas about how the web works (also, some straight up misunderstandings of web security, going by the default risk ratings for some of Burp Suite's scanner findings).

In particular, sending anti-CSRF tokens in hidden inputs of HTML forms is really only relevant if you're going to directly submit the form. If you're doing anything else - including any form of script-initiated requests (XHR/fetch/AJAX/etc.) - then the important thing is that the anti-CSRF value is included in that request, and by default it wouldn't be.

How it gets from the server to the client is quite irrelevant, provided it's not exposed to an attacker; it *could* come in the HTML, but that assumes you're serving dynamic HTML at all. If you're using a modern template-based dynamic UI framework, you're much better off sending the token in an API response body, or making it something the client can determine on their own using info the attacker wouldn't have (a hash of the session token/JWT is perfectly fine). Some sites will recommend using a cookie instead (the "double-cookie submit" pattern, where the same value is sent in the cookie and the body) but this is less secure than other options and should only be used if necessary. Double-cookie submit does allow the server to avoid needing to remember the anti-CSRF token (server-side stateless), but hashing the auth token, or just using a custom header (which is inherently protected against CSRF unless you go out of your way to hack down same-origin policy with excessive CORS), does that too.

Answer (score 0):

They should be included in POST paramaters, because if you include single-use tokens as GET parameters (i.e, in the URL) then you often break browser navigation features like history and the back button.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, the CSRF token can be transmitted via custom headers, cookies, query string parameters, or the body of requests -- so pretty much anywhere.

Previous posters mentioned the dangers of CSRF tokens within URLs, mostly because they will end up being logged by most webservers, end up in caches, bookmarks, browser history, and other places. However, the validity of the tokens should be short-lived, so exposing the token to these storage risks isn't a huge deal. Kind of like how much password reset functionalities provide a URL with a query string value with a password reset token. It's not a big deal because it should expire after it's used.

I'm also not sure the criticisms of double-submit implementations are *justified* enough to consider it "insecure". It's a beautiful thing to have client-side protections remain within the client, so the server doesn't need to have any visibility needed for storage & validation tasks, especially for single page applications. Sure, you'll need to set SecureOnly to prevent MiTM, but you can say the same thing about session cookies. The biggest flaw I can think of related to double-submit is one if it's strengths, the values aren't tied to sessions. If the browser stores a double-submit token, and the tokens aren't cycled properly, and the token is somehow exposed, and multiple people use the same computer, browser, and application, one CSRF token leaked could leave all of those people at risk of CSRF. But ya, that's a lot of *and's*.